# Eliminar una row seleccionada en un QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Se me presenta el siguiente problema trato de borrar una fila seleccionada de un TableWidget pero no funciona esta es la función que ocupo:

`self.check.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabla.selectedItems().clear())`

Y este es el codigo completo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5 import uic 




class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("columna.ui",self)

        self.tabla.insertRow(self.tabla.rowCount())
        self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,2,QTableWidgetItem("sdsd"))
        self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,1,QTableWidgetItem("sdsd"))
        self.tabla.insertRow(self.tabla.rowCount())
        self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,1,QTableWidgetItem("sdsd"))
        self.boton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabla.setShowGrid(False)) #Limpiar sin dejar la rejilla en la tabla

        self.check.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabla.selectedItems().clear()) #Función para eliminar solo una row




app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTableWidgetselectedItems` retorna una lista Python con los items seleccionados, por lo que `QTableWidgetselectedItems().clear()` lo que hace es aplicar el método `list.clear()`, limpiando la lista retornada pero nada más.

Si quieres eliminar la fila del item actual puedes obtener la fila con [`QTableWidget.currentRow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#currentRow) y usar  [`QTableWidget.removeRow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#removeRow)  para eliminarla:

```
self.check.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabla.removeRow(self.tabla.currentRow()))
```

Ten en cuenta que esto elimina la fila completa y sus itemns, no se limita a limpiar el contenido del item.

Comment: con respecto a la manera en que agrego las columnas he items, lo estoy haciendo bien o hay alguna manera mas especifica

Comment: Lo estás haciendo bien, no hay en principio un método más directo que el que usas. Se pueden añadir filas o columnas al final también mediante `setRowCount(rows: int)` y `setColumnCount(columns: int)`, son de utilidad si quieres agregar varias al mismo tiempo.